# How can I use XPath and DOM to replace a node/element in php?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Say I have the following html

```
$html = '
<div class="website">
    <div>
        <div id="old_div">
            <p>some text</p>
            <p>some text</p>
            <p>some text</p>
            <p>some text</p>
            <div class="a class">
                <p>some text</p>
                <p>some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="another_div"></div>
    </div>
</div>
';
```

And I want to replace `#old_div` with the following:

```
$replacement = '<div id="new_div">this is new</div>';
```

To give an end result of:

```
$html = '
<div class="website">
        <div>
            <div id="new_div">this is new</div>
            <div id="another_div"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
';
```

Is there an easy cut-and-paste function for doing this with PHP?

---

**Final working code thanks to all Gordon's help:**

```
<?php

$html = <<< HTML
<div class="website">
    <div>
        <div id="old_div">
            <p>some text</p>
            <p>some text</p>
            <p>some text</p>
            <p>some text</p>
            <div class="a class">
                <p>some text</p>
                <p>some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="another_div"></div>
    </div>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($html); // use loadHTML if it's invalid XHTML

//create replacement
$replacement  = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$replacement  ->appendXML('<div id="new_div">this is new</div>');

//make replacement
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$oldNode = $xp->query('//div[@id="old_div"]')->item(0);
$oldNode->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement  , $oldNode);
//save html output
$new_html = $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement);

echo $new_html;

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using DOMXPath to replace a node while maintaining its position ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640815/using-domxpath-to-replace-a-node-while-maintaining-its-position)

Comment: You can use **XPath for selecting** the target node to **replace with a DOM method**. Refrasing title.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the answer in the linked duplicate is not that comprehensive, I'll give an example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($html); // use loadHTML if its invalid (X)HTML

// create the new element
$newNode = $dom->createElement('div', 'this is new');
$newNode->setAttribute('id', 'new_div');

// fetch and replace the old element
$oldNode = $dom->getElementById('old_div');
$oldNode->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $oldNode);

// print xml
echo $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement);
```

---

Technically, you don't need XPath for this. However, it can happen that your version of libxml cannot do `getElementById` for non-validated documents ([id attributes are special in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/REC-xml-id-20050909/REC-xml-id-20050909.xml)). In that case, replace the call to `getElementById` with

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$oldNode = $xp->query('//div[@id="old_div"]')->item(0);
```

[Demo on codepad](http://codepad.org/EJ8e6QYk)

---

To create a `$newNode` with child nodes without having to to create and append elements one by one, you can do

```
$newNode = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$newNode->appendXML('
<div id="new_div">
    <p>some other text</p>
    <p>some other text</p>
    <p>some other text</p>
    <p>some other text</p>
</div>
');
```

Comment: @gordon `Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to DOMNode::replaceChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given in C:\wamp\www\gv2010\user_area\replacement-test.php on line 24` ?

Comment: @Gordon that's great. The reality behind my example is that `$replacement` html is much more complex than just a single node. Is there a way to use a string (heredoc) for the `$newNode` ?

Comment: @Haroldo See update. Try http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php

Comment: @Gordon - You sir, are an absolute legend.

Comment: @Haroldo I'd love to believe that, but nah, I just know my way around DOM and some of it's quirks ;) You're welcome.

Answer (score -7):

use jquery hide() first to hide particular div and then use append to append new div

```
$('#div-id').remove();
$('$div-id').append(' <div id="new_div">this is new</div>');
```

Comment: A question is about PHP (server side), not javascript (client side).

Comment: plus even if this was client side your solution is wrong because it is appending rather than replacing so would not preserve situe...