# Strip links, keep markup and text (with or without specific domains)

Tags: php, regex, dom, markup, dom-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Dom Remove element leave contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675460/php-dom-remove-element-leave-contents)

I'm adding a function to a WordPress theme's `function.php`.

I want to have it strip links from markup, something like this:

```
function clean_content($content) { <br>
    $content = preg_replace('some regex goes here, but what?', '', $content);
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'clean_content', 1);
```

What is the regex for stripping links but keeping the rest of the markup, but only for links from certain domains?

Per example, I want to strip all links that contain `google.com` in the `href` attribute, but keep the markup and text (e.g.: `<img>` for image links, etc.).

Thanks, thanks, thanks!

Comment: Use DOM, not regex (unless you're really good at regex, which you probably aren't since you are asking this question). See other question linked above.

Comment: Other tip: Use XPath to find nodes that contains specific domains in the link, like this: `//a[contains(@href, "google.com")]`, then remove those nodes.

Comment: This is very nice, thanks, but I'd like to have the regex for future purposes. You're correct, I'm not a regex guru, that's why I'm consulting with the Stack Overflow community. ;)
That is the reasons why I tagged it regex, not just php. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @netcoder The DOM solution is the right way to go, very elegant and is probably the way I'll go. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Tylerr: You can find all sorts of reasons why not to do that with regex on StackOverflow. Besides, it's way easier not to and has less unexpected side-effects (none if done correctly).

Comment: chances are with regex you will leave a way to slip in an anchor tag. <<a></a>a<a></a> <a></a>href=""<a></a>>click<<a></a>/a<a></a>>